# Google maps marker parsed using ajax json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

can someone tell me why I can't add multiple markers parsed via json inside and ajax request? I've build an array which should receive the json array which contains the information required to display the markers on the google map. But it strangely does not work at all! at any rate if I try to print in console the length of the array I can see the array is looping  correctly

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.90832, 12.52407)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "json/prova.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
var infowindow = [];
    var marker = [];
    function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr.length);
  console.log(infowindow.length);
            (function(i){ //new line 
            infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: arr[i].title
            });
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    title: arr[i].title,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,                        
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].latitude,arr[i].longitude)
                });
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
               infowindow[i].open(map,this);
            });
            })(i); //new line
    }
}
```

```css
    html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
         <title>Simple Map</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
         <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&amp;key=AIzaSyD3Xz7-z7U_XzZiaOlx9khhtFSld8vd0k4"></script>
        <script src="js/prova_simple.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>

  <h1>Customers</h1>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [
{
"title": "Coop.Sociale Prassi e Ricerca Onlus", 
"latitude": 41.9114145,
"longitude": 12.524204
},
{
"title": "Astronave", 
"latitude": 41.912333,
"longitude": 12.525531
},
{
"title": "Casa", 
"latitude": 41.877719,
"longitude": 12.558317
}
]

Comment: what I've just wrote is my json file that definitely works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not placing the marker in the map.

If you go to [markers documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) you can see several ways to do it.

I recommend for your case inside the `for` function:

```
marker[i].setMap(map)
```

### EDIT:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr.length);
        console.log(infowindow.length);
            (function(i){ //new line 
            infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: arr[i].title
            });
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    title: arr[i].title,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,                        
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].latitude,arr[i].longitude)
                });
             marker[i].setMap(map) //<----- HERE
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
               infowindow[i].open(map,this);
            });
            })(i); //new line
    }
```

Comment: i've added this but the console says that marker[i] is undefined. I've added your solution at the beginning of the for loop

Comment: added the for loop in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please push marker into the map

markers.push(marker);